# using domConstruct.create to make an "Option" drop down list, how Can I have a disable selected value?

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have the following html:

```
<tr>
<td class="userFormLabel">User Type:</td>
<td class="userFormText">
<select name="userType" data-dojo-attach-point="userTypesSelect">
</select> </td>
</tr>
```

And the following js:

```
var userTypeSelect = this.userTypesSelect;
array.forEach( userData.userTypes, function(item,idx) {
if (user != null && user.userTypeLookupId == item.id) {
    domConstruct.create("option", 
     {value:item.id,
      innerHTML:item.name,
      selected:'selected'}, 
      userTypeSelect);
} else {domConstruct.create("option", {
             value: item.id, 
             innerHTML: item.name},
             userTypeSelect);
   }
});
```

I would like to have the else condition give a non value display; for example a "" or "Choose User Type" text defaulted in the drop down rather than the first item in the list (item.id/userTypeSelect).  I attempted to do this in the html by adding the following to my html code:

```
<option selected disabled>choose user type</option>
```

But this didn't work, it seemed to be ignored.  I've scoured the dojo docs looking for a DOM attribute similar to the html code above, that I could use in the domConstruct but those docs are confusing and seem to be lacking in detail/clarity.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding a `value=""` to the disabled option (and possibly make it the first in the list)
Be aware that this is subject to browser compatibility, where some browsers may not behave as you would want.

Comment: So I added the following to my html:    'code' <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose Tagging</option>  this seemed to work.  Though now I need to see how the code handles if a save is attempted with that 'choose tagging' value is isn't changed.

Comment: I don't like the way you are creating the option element into the userTypeSelect in domConstruct.create(). I don't think that's the correct way to do it. Also, the 'selected' and 'disabled' attributes have no values, so you had that correct in your first sample. 
The way I insert options is that I create them using the 'document.createElement', and then assign the properties and attributes, and then add this option to the select via 'add()' http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp